# The grid store doesn't refresh in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have one store and two gridViews (grid1 and grid2) in my web application.
I need to load grid2 with grid1's store after grid1 loaded. I know there is many examples on internet for this case but I cannot done it. 
There is my code below to bind gridView2.

```
grid2.setStore(storeGrid1);
grid2.getStore().commitChanges();
grid2.getView().refresh;
```

**Note:** In fact grid2's store is changing (I checked it with browser's inspect element mode).

Data is binding but They don't seen on user interface. Other answers are about with Ext JS4, may be my code is doesn't work because of it. Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a store for grid2 is properly, then you can refresh view like this:

```
grid2.getStore().load(); // refresh store -> refresh view
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain stores in your viewModel, then bind them.

Look at the ExtJS 5 chainedStores example.